# How to extract first element of each child array in multidimensional array?

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, google-apps-script

I have a multidimensional array:

```
var array 1 = 

[

 [[Name 1, 2, Nigeria], 
  [Name 3, 52, Egypt], 
  [Name 5, 75, South Africa]]

 [[Name 5, 8, Nigeria], 
  [Name 1, 62, Egypt], 
  [Name 3, 115, South Africa]]

 [[Name 6, 88, Nigeria], 
  [Name 3, 92, Egypt], 
  [Name 5, 825, South Africa]]

 ]
```

I want to have a new flat array:

```
var array 2 = [Name 1, Name 3, Name 5, Name 5, Name 1, Name 3, Name 6, Name 3, Name 5]
```

I've tried writing a function that maps over the array and returns the first element:

```
function name(filteredName){
filteredName.map(function(firstName){
  return firstName[0]
})
```

}

However, this just returns:

```
[Name 1, Name 1, Name 1]
```

I'm really not sure how to solve this! Any help would be great.

Comment: is name supposed to be a key and 1 supposed to be the value of name? also what is Name and Country? are those types or strings?

Comment: No that is the full element. Would be easier if it was key/values.

Comment: so like Name = 1 and Nigeria = 2 or Name = [1, 2] and Nigeria = undefined?

Comment: Provide [mcve]. How are you calling `name()`? If you called `name(array1)`, It won't return anything. Your array isn't a array either. It's syntactically inaccurate. Your example is neither complete nor verifiable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use nested `map()` and then `flat()`

```js
var arr = [ [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']], [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']], [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']] ];
 
   const res = arr.map(x => x.map(a => a[0])).flat(2)
   console.log(res)
```

#### Without `flat()`

You can do that without using `flat()` using `concat()` and spread operator.

```js
var arr = [ [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']], [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']], [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']] ];
 
 const res = [].concat(...arr.map(x => x.map(x => x[0])))
 console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks. Although Google App Script uses ES5, so no arrow functions.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [Array.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat) and [Array.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
array1.flat().map(arr => arr[0]);
```

Or you can use [Array.concat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) instead of Array.flat():

```
[].concat(...array1).map(arr => arr[0]);
```

**Working example**:

```js
var array1 = [
 [
   ['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], 
   ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], 
   ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']
 ],

 [
   ['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], 
   ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], 
   ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']
 ],

 [
   ['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], 
   ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], 
   ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']
 ]
];

const NamesArr = array1.flat().map(arr => arr[0]);

console.log(NamesArr);
console.log('Array.concat():');
console.log([].concat(...array1).map(arr => arr[0]));
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a combination of [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and [`flatMap`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flatMap) like this:

```js
const array1 = [ [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']], [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']], [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']] ];

const output = array1.flatMap(a => a.map(b => b[0]))

console.log(output)
```

If `flatMap` is not supported, you could use a simple nested [`for...of`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of) loop:

```js
var array1 = [ [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']], [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']], [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']] ];

var output = [];

for (var arr of array1) {
  for (var arr2 of arr) {
    output.push(arr2[0])
  }
}

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 1):

I loop over the first array. In that loop, I loop over the second one and push the first entry.

```js
var array = [

 [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']],
 ];
 
var result = []

for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
    result.push(array[i][j][0])
  }
}

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Flatten your array before using `.map`. That way, you will not be working with a multidimensional array and it will be easier to get the first element of each array:

```js
var arr = 
[
 [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']]

 ]
 
 
 console.log(arr.flat().map(item => item[0]))
```

#### Notice

`.flat` does not have huge support yet, you can either use a [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat#Polyfill) if you want to use the latest code standard or use the spread operator to flatten your array:

```js
var arr = 
[
 [['Name 1', 2, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 52, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 75, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 5', 8, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 1', 62, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 3', 115, 'South Africa']],

 [['Name 6', 88, 'Nigeria'], 
  ['Name 3', 92, 'Egypt'], 
  ['Name 5', 825, 'South Africa']]

 ]
 
 
 console.log([].concat(...arr).map(item => item[0]))
```

Comment: For some reasons, I have *"TypeError: arr.flat is not a function"* and this for all answer using methods such as `flat()`, `map()`, `flatMap`

Comment: using firefox 60.6.3

Comment: You guys are 100% right, `.flat` has been introduced in firefox 62. Anyway, gave you an alternative

Answer (score 0):

you could also do it with forEach and spread syntax

```
var flatArr = [];

array_1.forEach((arr, i) => {
    arr.forEach(innerArr => {
        flatArr = [...flatArr, innerArr[0]]
    })
});
```